# Prove that if G is a connected graph of diameter 2, then λ(G) = δ(G).

Tags: graph-theory, proof-writing

Notation:

δ(G)= minimum degree of the graph G
λ(G)= minimum edge cuts to disconnect graph G

Let be v a vertex such that  δ(G)=d(v). I have that e(v)=2 because if not, then G would be complete graph. I suppose that δ(G)> λ(G) to get a contradiction by considering S an edge-minimum cut set and considering G´=G-S, but I´m stuck.

Can you help me with any suggestions?

Comment: You should say what you mean by $\delta$, etc... These notations are not fully standard.

Comment: δ(G)= minimum degree of the graph G
λ(G)= minimum edge cuts to disconnect graph G

Comment: Thanks. For example, I thought that $\lambda$ was connected to eigenvalues of some matrix.

Comment: Sorry, It was my mistake.

Comment: I guess $e(v)$ is the *eccentricity* of $v,$ the maximum distance from $v$ to another vertex in $G?$

Comment: You must be assuming that $G$ is a *simple* graph, i.e., no loops or multiple edges? There are simple counterexamples with multiple edges, e.g., take $C_4$ and double two non-adjacent edges.

Comment: Yes, the graph is simple and e(v) is the eccentricity. The diameter of G is 2 and I have that e(v)=2. I´ve tried to consider a S vertex cut set and, somehow, make a vu-path consists in at least 3 vertex.

Answer (score 2):

It should be clear that in any graph, $\lambda(G) \leq \delta(G)$ (take as a cut-set the edges incident to a vertex of minimum degree). Now we want to show that if the diameter of $G$ is 2, then $\lambda(G) = \delta(G)$.

You are right to want to assume that $\lambda(G) < \delta(G)$ and hope to derive a contradiction. Let $S$ be some cut set of size $\lambda(G)$ and let $A$ be the vertices on one side of the cut set and $B$ the vertices on the other (be careful to clarify this definition and think about why $A$ and $B$ are well-defined). Our goal will be to find a vertex of $A$ and a vertex of $B$ that are not incident to any edge of $S$, thus showing the diameter is 3. We will focus on finding this vertex for $A$ ($B$ is similar).

Assume no such vertex of $A$ exists. Let $v$ be a vertex of $A$ and let $k \geq 1$ be the number of edges of $S$ incident to $v$. There must be at least $d(v) - k$ neighbors of $v$ in $A$, and every other vertex of $A$ is incident to at least one of the $|S|-k$ edges of $S$ not already incident to $v$, so

$$ \lambda(G)-k+1 = |S|-k+1 \geq |A| \geq d(v)-k+1 \geq \delta(G)-k+1 .$$

Oh wait! This calculation gives us a direct contradiction with our original assumption. I've left in my thought-processes to show that sometimes "following your nose" reveals in a simpler proof which would have been harder to discover originally. Indeed, let me reword the above to provide a simple, direct proof:

Let $S$ be some cut set of size $\lambda(G)$ and let $A$ and $B$ be the vertices of the two components of $G \setminus S$ (again, make sure $A$ and $B$ are well-defined). If there is a vertex of $A$ not incident to any edge of $S$ and a vertex of $B$ not incident to any edge of $S$, then the diameter of $G$ must be at least 3. Since $G$ has diameter 2, in at least one of $A$ or $B$ no such vertex exists. Without loss of generality, suppose every vertex of $A$ is incident to an edge of $S$.

Let $v$ be a vertex of $A$ and let $k \geq 1$ be the number of edges of $S$ incident to $v$. There must be at least $d(v) - k$ neighbors of $v$ in $A$, and every other vertex of $A$ is incident to at least one of the $|S|-k$ edges of $S$ not already incident to $v$, so

$$ \lambda(G)-k = |S|-k \geq |A\setminus\{v\}| \geq d(v)-k \geq \delta(G)-k .$$

Thus $\lambda(G) \geq \delta(G)$, as desired.

Comment: Beautiful! Thank you for sharing your insights.